# Regular Expression up to but do not include character

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

This has been done before and I have tried to customize my regex based on other entries in Stack Exchange but I am having a hard time grasping it...

What I need is to match a query string parameter in a rewritecond and take the parameter value of the cond and insert it in a new string.

My cond is:

```
WT.mc_id=(\S+&|\S+$)
```

This gives me close to what I need.  But I do NOT want the `&` in the `%1` value for the rewriterule.

So when someone gives me `WT.mc_id=foo&bar=whatever` I want `foo`, not `foo&`.  I also don't want an empty string but I can check for that in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex instead:

```
(^|&)WT\.mc_id=([^&]*)
```

Comment: @fred02138: That is intentional as whatever query string has should be captured in `%1`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
WT\.mc_id=(\S+?)(?:&|$)
```

This will match a literal `WT.mc_id=` followed by one or more non-white-space characters, non-greedily, captured in group 1, followed by either an ampersand or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
WT.mc_id=(\w+)
```

it is the most simple solution I could come up with.
You can also check it and play around [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/Q8AoiogBVg)